# How to give a dynamic textbox a default value based on another dynamic dropdown and textbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am looking to do the following.  Trying to get the Quantity column textboxes to have a default value based on dropdown and textbox in the same dynamic table.

So in picture below when Unit dropdown is set as 2 and then input the Quantity is 5 in row 2, any row below would have a default quantity from row 2.  So row 6 & 7 should have default value as 5.

[image]

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <form method="post" id="insert_form">
    <div class="table-repsonsive">
     <span id="error"></span>
     <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
      <tr>
       <th>Unit</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Quantity</th>
       <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
let restricts = ["bags", "kg"];
function hideQuantity(e) {
    if (restricts.indexOf(e.target.value) > -1) {
        e.target.closest("tr").querySelector(".item_quantity").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        e.target.closest("tr").querySelector(".item_quantity").removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.add', function () {
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td><select onclick="hideQuantity(event)" name="item_unit[]" id="item_unit" class="form-control item_unit">';
        html += '<option value="">Select Unit</option><option value="bags">Bags</option><option value="inch">Inch</option><option value="kg">Kg</option><?php echo numopt(); ?>';
        html += '</select></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]"" class="form-control item_name" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_quantity[]"" class="form-control item_quantity" /></td>';
        html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
        $('#item_table').append(html);
    });

 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 });
    
 $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var error = '';
  $('.item_name').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '') {
    error += "<p>Enter Item Name at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
  
  $('.item_quantity').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '') {
    error += "<p>Enter Item Quantity at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
  
  $('.item_unit').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '') {
    error += "<p>Select Unit at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
     
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  if(error == '') {
   $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data) {
     if(data == 'ok') {
      $('#item_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
      $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Item Details Saved</div>');
     }
    }
   });
  } else {
   $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
  }
 });
});

</script>
```

Comment: So it triggers after you update Quantity value and being sure a Unit is selected... ? [Quantity input onchange]=>get selected val() "Reference"=>each select compare $('#Select').val() to Reference=>if equal update quantity field in the same line ()

Comment: It's just the idea/algorithm... I'll post an answer tomorrow if you didn't solve it.

Comment: I have tried and failed.  I can get the quality to default to a value but not based on value from above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED] to offer update from both ways. I hope it's working like your expected results (*but still like I suggested in my comment, *it's advised to think about another way to manage this using a technique that is not "Design-dependant". Like Javascript objects or LocalStorage...** )

```js
let restricts = ["bags", "kg"];
function hideQuantity(e) {
    if (restricts.indexOf(e.target.value) > -1) {
        e.target.closest("tr").querySelector(".item_quantity").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        e.target.closest("tr").querySelector(".item_quantity").removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.add', function () {
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td><select onclick="hideQuantity(event)" name="item_unit[]" id="item_unit" class="form-control item_unit">';
        html += '<option value="">Select Unit</option><option value="bags">Bags</option><option value="inch">Inch</option><option value="kg">Kg</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>';
        html += '</select></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]"" class="form-control item_name" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_quantity[]"" class="form-control item_quantity" /></td>';
        html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
        $('#item_table').append(html);
    });

 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 });
    
    $(document).on('change keyup focusout','.item_quantity',function(){
        //I called it in french to avoid confusion with value val...
        var valeur =$(this).val();
        var unitreference= $(this).parents("tr").find("td:first select.item_unit").val();
        $('.item_unit').each(function(){
            if($(this).val()==unitreference ){
                $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(2) input.item_quantity").val(valeur).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
    })
    
    $(document).on('change','.item_unit',function(){
        //Update using the unit selector
        var selectedUnit =$(this).val();
        //Here we look for the Quantity field being used as Referece
        var quantRef= $('select option[value='+selectedUnit+']:selected').parents("tr").find("td:eq(2) input.item_quantity:not(:disabled)").val()
        //console.log(selectedUnit)     
        //console.log(quantRef)
        if(quantRef){
        $('.item_unit').each(function(){
            if($(this).val()==selectedUnit ){
                $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(2) input.item_quantity").val(quantRef).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            
        });
        }
    })
    
 $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var error = '';
  $('.item_name').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '') {
    error += "<p>Enter Item Name at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
  
  $('.item_quantity').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '') {
    error += "<p>Enter Item Quantity at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
  
  $('.item_unit').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '') {
    error += "<p>Select Unit at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
     
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  if(error == '') {
   $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data) {
     if(data == 'ok') {
      $('#item_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
      $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Item Details Saved</div>');
     }
    }
   });
  } else {
   $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <form method="post" id="insert_form">
    <div class="table-repsonsive">
     <span id="error"></span>
     <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
      <tr>
       <th>Unit</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Quantity</th>
       <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

P.S: Sorry I was busy :) An advice : If it's possible, you could add some classes on cell tables so you could optimize your code using closest().

Comment: Bilel, this is great but 2 things.

1. is there a way to update item_quantity if item_unit selected is the same?
2. is there a way to disable item_quantity that are later added that are the same but the first item_quantity not disabled so that it may be changed and update below matching item_quantity?

Comment: Is it like what I asked for in my answer : You would like to update quantities values if unit selector is being updated? And for the second option : You mean keeping only one Quantity field (used as reference) and disabling all inputs that copied it's value? Possible :) But you need to think about UX too and how your users could understand that ;) I'll try to update it